# Magento 2 - Multiline content for static block installer

Tags: magento2

What is best practice on Magento 2 for having multiline html in content? On Magento 1 if I remember right you would use some thing <<<'EOT'

I'm getting syntax errors on this:

```
$cmsBlockData = [
    'title' => "test block",
    'identifier' => "test-block",
    'content' => "<div>
                    <img src="{{view url="images/content/about-us-img2.jpg"}}" alt="" />
                  </div>",
    'is_active' => 1,
    'stores' => [0],
    'sort_order' => 0
];
```

Comment: can you add that error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<<<EOD` as used in [CreateDefaultPages.php file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Setup/Patch/Data/CreateDefaultPages.php#L109)

In your case it will be like :

```
$blockContent = <<<EOD
<div>
   <img src="{{view url="images/content/about-us-img2.jpg"}}" alt="" />
</div>
EOD;

$cmsBlockData = [
    'title' => "test block",
    'identifier' => "test-block",
    'content' => $blockContent,
    'is_active' => 1,
    'stores' => [0],
    'sort_order' => 0
];
```

This is called using the PHP Heredoc string syntax. [Here's the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) on it if you need to read more about it (and it's *stricter* brother, Nowdoc, a little further down)

Answer (score 0):

actually there are four types of strings available in php. They are single quotes (`'`), double quotes (`"`) and Nowdoc (`<<<'EOD'`) and heredoc(`<<<EOD`) strings. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924540/4956508)

You can use here document operator (<<<) then use a word like HTML, EOD, EOT or any string you want!

---

- Some handy notes when you wanna use heredoc : [here](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/php/php-here-document-heredoc-syntax-examples)
- Sample :

```
$html = <<<HTML
        <div class="intro-block" style="background-image: url({{view url='images/content/about-us-img1.jpg'}})">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
HTML;

        $cmsBlockData = [
            'title' => "About Us",
            'identifier' => "aboutus",
            'content' => $html
            ",
        ]
```